# Interface method with different parameters

Tags: php, oop

I have assign subjects to certain group, there's multiple algorithms to do this but they need various of method parameters to calculate output.

For example we can have

```php
interface Algorithm {
   randomize(???) : int
}

class A implements Algorithm {
   randomize(int, int) : int
}

class B implements Algorithm {
   randomize(int, int, string) : int
}
```

The idea is to add another method for the Algorithm interface, setup() and create structure like this

```php
abstract class Configurer {
   private __constructor;

   // for which subject we need to take info. from db 
   init(int $subjectId) : Configurer
   setup(Algorithm) : void;
}

interface Algorithm {
   randomize() : int
   setup(Configurer) : void
   isConfigured() : bool
}
```

It solves problem of parameters which are stored in db but i still don't know how to handle additional parameters passed by users in form. Should i pass also form parameters as array to Configurer::init ?

Comment: Sounds like you should not use a common interface for these classes, if their methods do not use a common signature

Answer (score 1):

You can have variable amount of parameters passed in:

```php
interface Algorithm {
    public function randomize(mixed ...$params): int;
}
```

then when using it:

```
$a = new A();

// Call in different ways:
$a->randomize(someParameter: 1, anotherParameter: 2);
$a->randomize(...['someParameter' => 1, 'anotherParameter' => 2]);
$a->randomize(1, 2);
```

Comment: yea, this was also on my list but i would like to avoid unpacking arguments if it's possible, it requires to do validations on every single param (type, not null etc.) in randomize method.

Comment: @Boorsuk Are these parameters always _random_ or has pre-defined structure? E.g. we are using data mapper classes where instead of array with random keys you pass in specific class with pre-defined properties. Maybe that can help?

Comment: Every algorithm have predefined static and dynamic parameters, but i am not sure if i get the concept with mapper, at the begining i was thinking about some DtosFactory which are gonna change array to object (you are passing array and full class name) but i am not sure how to use it in the randomize method cause you need to type hint specific class.

Comment: @Boorsuk You can typehint interface or parent class only

Comment: Yea, but dtos dont have any parent/interface. I see only one way to do it with dtos, you have master DTO which implement method get(string $param) and every AlgorithmDtoParams extends AppDto